# OpenH264 isn't downloading for Firefox for WebRTC

Tags: windows-10, firefox, firefox-extensions, h.264, windows-iot-core

Environment:
Windows 10 IoT Enterprise 2019 LTSC - win64
Firefox ESR 78.3.1

The plugin OpenH264 isn't downloading properly, it is needed for Webex teams SDK to work. We have tried all the options available to check in terms of configuration but nothing worked

If anyone had a similar problem and resolved it, it would be great if one can share a possible solution

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't downloading properly"?  Also, how long did you wait?

Comment: i have waited for quite long, but i think it doesn't download at all because in the **about:plugins** it says it will download shortly and is like that forever.

Comment: I think I've seen it take 10+ minutes at times.  I once had to throw away a detailed bug report because I discovered the real issue was that the requisite plugin wasn't downloaded quickly.  It would be good to know what determines when it is downloaded.